# Problems with InitWithData

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to InitWithData a viewcontroller with multiple data like this:

```
 NewsDetailViewController *anotherViewController = [[NewsDetailViewController alloc]      initWithData:[oldEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
 [anotherViewController release];   
 [newsTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
```

So this is the current:  InitWithData:initWithData:[oldEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

Now I need the InitWithData to push 2 of these objects:

```
[oldEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[reviewEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

How can I do this?

I receive the current data like this in the NewsDetailController:

```
- (id)initWithData:(NSDictionary *)data {
    if (self == [super init]) {        
    rssData = [data copy];  

    }
    return self;
}
```

And rssData is a NSDictionary..

Comment: I mean that 'xml' is insufficient tagging,and your question doesn't explain anything more.

Comment: The initWithData:[oldEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; pushes a article array that has been parsed from XML to a detailviewcontroller thats shows it. This works. But now im parsing the XML 2 times for special reasons, now i need to give both data to the detail view. So a dubble InitWithdata.

Answer (score 1):

change your init method to

```
 - (id)initWithOldData:(NSDictionary *)oldData 
       andReviewData:(NSDictionary *)revData {
  if (self == [super init]) {        
  rssOldData = [oldData copy];  
  rssReviewData = [revData copy]; 
  }
  return self;
}
```

and call it using

```
[[NewsDetailViewController alloc] 
 initWithOldData:[oldEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
 andReviewData:[reviewEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Of course you need to declare `rssOldData`and `rssReviewData` in your `NewsDetailViewController` too.